# how can I log the current threadcount in SOAPUI?

Tags: soapui

I need to create a log file from a SOAPUI load test that shows the threadcount at 1-second intervals.  The file needs only a timestamp and the threadcount, and can be CSV or any other format really.  I can't see a way to get just this info from the predefined log files.

Is a Groovy script step the right way to do this?  How would I write it?  I could have a test case that does nothing but writes the log message every second while the "real" cases are running concurrently, but I don't know how to write that simple bit of script.  I find the documentation almost impenetrable.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

This runs faster than once per second.  If it works for you I can explain how to cut the time down:

```
if (context.LoadTestContext != null)
{
    log.info("threads = " + testRunner.getRunContext().LoadTestRunner.getRunningThreadCount() )
}
```

(It is a Groovy script)

By the way, load test script logging is off by default in SoapUI.  You need to go to Preferences, UI Settings & check the "Do not disable the groovy log when running load tests" checkbox.

Comment: Appreciate if you could help to log the threadIndex similarly.