# Load testing with SOAP UI

Tags: web-services, soap, soapui, load-testing

I have a `SOAP UI 4.5.1`, I have made a load test, it is working fine. My problem is that I run the same request every time and I need to change the values of the soap request I am sending.

For e.g. I have a block of my soap request:

```
 <ns:Assessment>
    <ns:Project>
       <ns:ProviderId>SHL</ns:ProviderId>
       <ns:ProjectId>SampleAssessment</ns:ProjectId>
    </ns:Project>
 </ns:Assessment>
```

Provider ID: SHL
Project ID: SampleAssessment

Is there a way to make those values changing from some kind of interval?
For e.g.: Provider IDs `[SHL, SLH, LHS]`
Project IDs `[SampleAssessment, TestAssessment, AnotherAssessment]`

And with a load test I am making three request so that for the first request values looks like this:

```
 <ns:Assessment>
    <ns:Project>
       <ns:ProviderId>SHL</ns:ProviderId>
       <ns:ProjectId>SampleAssessment</ns:ProjectId>
    </ns:Project>
 </ns:Assessment>
```

for the second like this:

```
 <ns:Assessment>
    <ns:Project>
       <ns:ProviderId>SLH</ns:ProviderId>
       <ns:ProjectId>TestAssessment</ns:ProjectId>
    </ns:Project>
 </ns:Assessment>
```

and so on...

Is there a way to make this happen with SOAP UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple way of doing this without writing a groovy script.

After creating a test case you should include the below test steps:

1-Data source

2-Request

3-Loop

Data source will read an excel file (or other data source methods such as XML, groovy, JDBC, gird .. however the excel is the simplest one).
You should include the datas (that you need to change within the request)

Within the test request you need the right click and select "get data" . please notice that your test request should be as below

```
<ns:ProviderId>${ProviderId}</ns:ProviderId>
```

Then the last step is the "Loop" . This for returning to the first step until the data ends.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, you will need to use a Groovy Script step.

For example, if you have a step before your request that is a script, you can use something like:

```
context.setProperty("ProviderId", "SHL")
```

Then in your request, use:

```
<ns:ProviderId>${ProviderId}</ns:ProviderId>
```

Of course, this doesn't buy you much by itself.  There are few ways to vary what the context.setProperty("ProviderId", "SHL") line will set.  You can create a collection and iterate over it using something like:

```
 def providers = ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'JKL']

 providers.each() {
     context.setProperty("ProviderId", it)
     testRunner.runTestStepByName( "nameofteststep" )
 }
```

Where "nameofteststep" is the name of the Soap Request test step.  This might sound odd, but if you right click the test step and disable it, the groovy script will still be able to execute it but it will not run sequentially.  By that I mean that the groovy script will run it 4 times, but it won't run a fifth time when the script is complete because it is after the script.  Then you just need to keep in mind that each load test thread makes four requests, but I am pretty sure that the SoapUI statistics will take this into account for you... might want to keep an eye out for it, though.

Alternatively, you could check the 'threadIndex' and set a the context variable based on that.  A bit like this here:   [Log ThreadCount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10543071/how-can-i-log-the-current-threadcount-in-soapui).

You could also use a collection without a loop and increment an index that you save as a testcase property and send the string corresponding to the index.

Personally, I think the first way is the most straightforward but I can provide an example of the other ones if you like.